# How do I quote in a paper a quote that someone else used in a book?

Tags: quotes

I'm writing a paper using Aldous Huxley's The Perennial Philosophy. Huxley doesn't use a single word when he quotes, his book is full of complete quotes that aren't a part of a sentence or a paragraph, and he uses the quotes as supporting evidence to what he has said. For example, take this as a paragraph from the book. End paragraph.

```
 He who suffers for love does not suffer, for all suffering is forgot.
                                                          -Eckhart
```

How do I quote this quote in my paper?

Comment: Is your intention to quote Eckhart or Huxley?

Comment: Your entire paper is based on Aldous Huxley's *The Perennial Philosophy* (I presume). If so, just cite the page number against each such reference. *He who suffers ... is forgot. -Eckhart*  **[p.xxx]**

Comment: Have you asked the Q on writersSE?

Answer (score 3):

You would quote the original with an "as cited by" mention. For example

> Writing in his *The Perennial Pilosophy*, Huxley quotes Eckhart: "He who suffers for love does not suffer, for all suffering is forgot."*

*[Eckhart citation here]

Answer (score 0):

I  always heard to use double quotation marks for the quote from the text you're pulling it from, then using single quotation marks for the quote within the text. For example... King states, "You may ask, 'why the...'"